# why is jquery is not updating my variable in the <span>?

Tags: php, jquery

my code:

```
if ($numOfMessages <> 0)
{
    echo "<span class='headings_sub' id='msgcntDiv'>You have " .$numOfMessages . "</span>";
    echo "<a class='red_link' href='".ADDRESS."messages.php'> unopened Messages</a>";
}
```

Jquery:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        refresh();
    });

    function refresh()
    {      
        $.get('newMessageCnt.php', function (cnt) {
        $("#msgcntDiv").data('cnt', cnt);
        window.setTimeout(refresh,30000);
        });   
    }   
</script>
```

newMessageCnt.php:

```
<?php
include('header_application.php');
$obj_clean->check_user();  //$obj_clean defined/initialized in header_application
echo $obj_clean->getUnopenedMessagesCount($_SESSION['user_id']);
?>
```

any advise please?
thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
function refresh()
{      
    $.get('newMessageCnt.php', function (cnt) {

    $("#msgcntDiv").html("You have "+cnt);

    window.setTimeout(refresh,30000);
    });   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function refresh()
    {      
        $.get('newMessageCnt.php', function (cnt) {
        $("#msgcntDiv").html(cnt);
        window.setTimeout(refresh,30000);
        });   
    }
```

don't use `data()`, use `html()`

Answer (score 0):

You are adding data to the element instead of changing it's contents. Try:

```
$("#msgcntDiv").text(cnt);
```

Instead of:

```
$("#msgcntDiv").data('cnt', cnt);
```